If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, is $(A \times B)/A$ isomorphic to $B$?
If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, is $(A \times B)/(A\times \{0_B\})$ isomorphic to $B$? If not, do we need additional conditions?

Try to apply the First Isomorphism Theorem of Groups for an appropriate morphism from $A\times B$ onto $B$.

Blue, I have changed it a bit to make it look nicer. Feel free to roll back if I have altered the meaning.

There is a fairly obvious candidate isomorphism, and it works.

Welcome to MSE! <> As originally worded the question does not strictly make sense, because $A$ is not a subgroup of $A \times B$. Could you please clarify whether the subgroup is (i) $A \times {0_{B}}$ as edited; (ii) An arbitrary subgroup isomorphic to $A$; or (iii) something else?

Hint: Try using the map $\varphi : A \times B \to B$ defined by $\varphi(a, b) = b$ for all $(a, b) \in A \times B$.
Then

show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism,
determine the kernel of $\varphi$ and
determine the image of $\varphi$

Finally use the First Isomorphism Theorem that is
$$
(A \times B)/\ker(\varphi) \cong \mathrm{Im}(\varphi).
$$
